# Bubble plot in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am working with this kind of table in Excel...

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvM6f.jpg)

I would like to represent my data using a bubble plot where:

- The X axis represents the **Atts** row.
- The Y axis represents the **IDs** column.
- The size of the bubble represents the **number** connected to an
  unique ID and Att.

How can I do that?

---

*Example:*

**Dataset**:

```
      Att1 Att2 Att3
ID1      1    2    4
ID2      4    7    1
ID3      5    8    1
```

**Bubble plot**:

```
ID1 -|   (1)    (2)    (4)
     |
ID2 -|   (4)    (7)    (1) 
     |
ID3 -|   (5)    (8)    (1)
     |________________________
         Att1   Att2   Att3
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample chart with a smaller dataset?

Comment: Added! I hope It helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add lines with the X-axis values for each series like this:

[image]

(No need to highlight them, but it does make it easier to differentiate data from position)

Then insert a bubble chart:

[image]

Note: You will have to add axis labels manually

Comment: Thank you; it's a shame that Excel doesn't allow you to label the axes automatically...

Comment: Change your axis scales so they increment by 1, not 0.5. Use a custom number format of `"ID"0;;;` for the Y axis and `"Att"0;;;` for the X axis.